# convert trigger from FB to MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

I need your help. I use a trigger for Firebird Database. Now I have changed to MSSQL 2014 Database. 
I have one trigger and I could not convert this. Please give me your help. I need the following trigger to work in MSSQL

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUTOGENEHMIGEN_BU FOR DATEPARAMS 
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE dutyuid integer;

BEGIN 
if (new.PARAMUID in (2,25) and new.AVALUE > CURRENT_DATE-7) then
begin
    select uid from duties where uid=new.DUTYUID 
    into :dutyuid;
    if(dutyuid>0) then 
        update duties set status='R' where uid=:dutyuid;
end
END
```

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: What have you tried? Don't expect us to do your work... But we can assist if you run into a specific problem!

Comment: I have no good idea, because "before instead" is not possible in MSSQL. And instead to initialize a variable with : I have to use @ - > Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you need to look at. MSSQL does not support before triggers or row by row triggers (so you cannot use the new. or old. constructs)
and you have to use cursors to emulate row by row triggers.

To give you a start here's an after update trigger on users where I am writing the old and new values to an errors table.

```
USE [Sandbox]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[users]    Script Date: 25/04/2017 16:01:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    [user_id] [int] NULL,
    [contact_type_id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

user_id     contact_type_id value
----------- --------------- --------------------
1           2               aaa
1           3               aaa
2           1               example@mail.com
3           1               example2@mail.com
3           2               123345
3           3               skypeLogin2

(6 row(s) affected)

--drop trigger tai_users
CREATE TRIGGER TAI_users
on users 
after update 
AS

BEGIN 
 declare old cursor for select  value from deleted
 declare new cursor for select  value from inserted
 declare @oldvalue as varchar(20)
 declare @newvalue as varchar(20)

 open old
 open new
 fetch next from old into @oldvalue
 fetch next from new into @newvalue
  insert into errors (msg) values (concat(@oldvalue,',',@newvalue))
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       FETCH NEXT FROM old INTO @oldvalue 
       fetch next from new into @newvalue
       insert into errors (msg) values (concat(@oldvalue,',',@newvalue))
END   
  close old
  close new
  deallocate old
  deallocate new
END

--truncate table errors
update users 
    set value = 'bbb'
    where user_id = 1

select * from errors
select * from users

2           aaa,bbb
3           aaa,bbb
4           aaa,bbb

(4 row(s) affected)

user_id     contact_type_id value
----------- --------------- --------------------
1           2               bbb
1           3               bbb
2           1               example@mail.com
3           1               example2@mail.com
3           2               123345
3           3               skypeLogin2
```